# Object "main" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote this script to better understand Ruby's `self`, but I can't really wrap my head around these statements:

```
def self.test1
  'test1'
end

def test2
  'test2'
end

puts test1 #=> 'test1'
puts test2 #=> 'test2'
puts self.test1 #=> 'test1'
puts self.test2 # test1.rb:12:in `<main>': private method `test2' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

If `self.test2` doesn't work, why does `test1`? Does it have something to do with the behavior of the `main` object?

Does it have something to do with singleton objects? I know that in Ruby when you say `def foo.bar`, you're defining a bar method on a foo object? How does this fact relate to the original question about why `self2.test2` fails?

Comment: *why does `test1`?*--Do you mean "why does `self.test1`"?

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods defined on the main object become private by default. You can override that, though.

```
public def foo; "foo" end
puts self.foo # => "foo"
```

The tricky thing is that class methods defined on the main environment become available to the main object.